# Flutter - Should firebase_options.dart be added to gitignore?

Tags: flutter

When [initializing/configuring FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli#generating-firebase-options) a `firebase_options.dart` file is created at the root of `/lib`. This file contains api keys for android, ios, web, and whatever channels you may be using. Are these public keys that can go into a repo or private and should not be committed to a repo? There are no details on FlutterFire and to have this created in `/lib` seems to suggest these are public keys.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to share the API keys on github, these API keys are used to identify the project but cannot be used to grant access to the project itself, in this regard, they are more like usernames than passwords.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different)